# How do I set the correct screen resolution/scaling in fedora 35 kde like in windows 10?

Tags: fedora, kde

I am very new to the Linux world and I am using fedora as my operating system. When I was in windows, the screen resolution and scaling was perfect. But now everything looks so small. I tried changing the fonts, but still some things managed to be small. I tried to increase the scaling and some texts like title bar, etc came out blurry. Even normal websites that I am very familiar with feel like I’m using them on 75% zoom.

`neofetch` shows my screen resolution to be `1366*768` but in the display settings, my resolution is `1920x1080`. I used to use the same resolution when I was on windows.

This is my screenshot after increasing the scale. The titlebar is clearly iffy and my layout overflows.
[image: The blurry image after increasing scale]

Comment: It is hard to know what you want. I don't use windows 10. I am using KDE plasma on Debian: there are setting for font size, taskbar size, window frame size, and for some other display elements. If you show some images with markings and explanations of what you want changing, them we may be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You want *scaling* for the font and UI element sizes. Open the settings and go to the "displays" tab (or just press "enter" and then start typing "display"), and then set the "Scale" setting to e.g. 150%.

Comment: Increasing the scale does increase everything but like I said, it makes things blurry

Comment: huh, it really should not! This doesn't scale the "pixel image", it really just tells the system that "hey, if someone says the font is 12 pt, that's 1.5× as large as usual", basically. The rendering is still done on 1920×1080. It's what I do to work with my 2840 pixel wide display on my 13-inch laptop!

Comment: Yeah That's what I thought but it blurs things like titlebar on my laptop. Do you there is some issue with my display driver?

Comment: @S.Karki that's very unlikely a symptom.

Comment: @S.Karki Can you show a screen-shot. And a photo.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes I've edited the original question and added a screenshot. my latte layout is overflowing and the titlebar is visibly weird looking.